# Enter key as tab not working properly in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls, datagridviewtextboxcell

i have created a custom datagridview and trying to move my cell to the right when i presses enter key (instead of going to down on pressing enter key ) but i found that i have to press enter twice to move rightwards . when i presses enter key first time , it still go downwards (default way) and then if i presses enter again ,then it moves to right .

```
public partial class Paymentdatagridview : DataGridView
{
    public Paymentdatagridview()
    {
        // i have set enableheadervisualstyles to false 
        // make bold the headers
        // Add the columns to your custom DataGridView
        DataGridViewColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column1.Name = "Column1";
        column1.HeaderText = "Particulars";
        column1.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        column1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        this.Columns.Add(column1);

        DataGridViewColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column2.Name = "Column2";
        column2.HeaderText = "Amount";
        column2.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        column2.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        this.Columns.Add(column2);

        this.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        this.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold);
        this.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;          
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the current cell to the first cell and enable editing when the control receives focus
        if (RowCount > 0 && ColumnCount > 0)
        {
            CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[0];
            BeginEdit(true);
        }

        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Move the focus to the next column and row when Enter key is pressed
            if (CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                if (CurrentCell.RowIndex == RowCount - 1)
                {
                    // Reached the last cell, move focus to the first cell
                    CurrentCell = Rows[0].Cells[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    // Move to the first cell of the next row
                    CurrentCell = Rows[CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Cells[0];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Move to the next column
                CurrentCell = Rows[CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1];
            }

            BeginEdit(true);
            e.Handled = true;
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the key to enter a value into the cell and move right is already available. And this key is Tab. This is more or less standard. Just use Tab and don't waste your time.

If you, despite this, want to change defaults, just replace 'Keys.Enter' by 'Keys.Tab' (handle both KeyDown and KeyPress events). Or try to catch keys at form's level and replace Enter by Tab if DatagridView is in focus.